# Hörmander's hypoellipticity theorem for complex coefficients

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, differential-operators, linear-pde, schwartz-distributions

Hörmander's theorem says that if $L = \sum _{i=1} ^r X_i ^2+ X_0 + f$ on some open subset $U \subseteq \Bbb R$ has the property that the Lie algebra generated by $\{X_0, \dots, X_r\}$ at every point has real dimension $n$, then $L$ is hypoelliptic. Here, all vector fields are assumed to be real.

Is there any version for the case when the vector fields are complex? A quick look at Marco Bramanti's "An Invitation to Hypoelliptic Operators and Hörmander Vector Fields" doesn't seem to address this.

Answer (score 2):

You will find a study of self-adjoint operators of type
$$
\sum_{j=1}^r(X_j^*-iY_j^*)(X_j+iY_j),
$$
where $X_j, Y_j$ are real-valued vector fields for instance in the Helffer-Nier Lecture Note (Lecture Notes in Mathematics, 1862, Springer-Verlag, 2005). The geometry of complex vector fields is much more complicated than in the real case. Just to give a simple example, the 2D vector fields
$$
\partial_{x_1}+ix_1^{2k}\partial_{x_2}
$$ 
are hypoelliptic as well as their adjoints, although
$$
\partial_{x_1}+ix_1^{2k+1}\partial_{x_2}
$$
is micro-hypoelliptic at $\xi_2=1, \xi_1=0, x_1=0$ and not micro-hypoelliptic at $\xi_2=-1$, $\xi_1=0$, $x_1=0$.

On the other hand, L. H\"ormander is studying non-self-adjoint pseudo-differential operators in Chapter 27 of the fourth volume of his treatise ALPDO, a nice reading.

Comment: I shall take a look at these references, but do they contain anything about hypoellipticity?

Comment: Yes of course, Chapter 27 in ALPDO is studying subelliptic pseudodifferential operators which are special cases of  hypoelliptic operators.